# Unable to generate a response from SOAP request in Python

Tags: python, api, soap

I'm working on an API with the local url: http://localhost:8003/BioRad.PCR.CommandManager/SOCFXCommandService?wsdl
This requires the Bio-Rad CFX application to be opened to access the url.

I created the client with the zeep library using the code:
`client = Client(wsdl = 'http://localhost:8003/BioRad.PCR.CommandManager/SOCFXCommandService?wsdl')`

The API service `XmlCommand` requires xml as an input so I convert my Python object to xml using the `dicttoxml` library

```
def Message2XML(message_type_object):
message = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(message_type_object, custom_root='Message')
return message

data = {'RegistrationID': "", 
    'RegisterService': ""}
    
xml = Message2XML(data)
```

Running `python -mzeep http://localhost:8003/BioRad.PCR.CommandManager/SOCFXCommandService?wsdl` on the console gives:

```
Service: SOCFXCommandService
 Port: WSDualHttpBinding_ISOCFXCommandService (Soap12Binding: {http://tempuri.org/}WSDualHttpBinding_ISOCFXCommandService)
     Operations:
        OnServiceIsClosing(missing input message)
        SubscribeToServiceIsClosing() ->
        XmlCommand(xml: xsd:string) -> XmlCommandResult: xsd:string
```

The output console just gives a `None` as a response even though it supposes to give back an xml output. Below is the message that was sent and the response that I got.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Message>
    <RegistrationID type="str"/>
    <RegisterService type="str"/>
</Message>

None
```

Comment: Is that how your XML message looks on the wire? Because if it is, it's wrong. You need to send a properly formatted SOAP XML message, not just an XML. You are also not sending any data for `RegistrationID` and `RegisterService`. Does the service call really work without those?

Comment: Could you show me how to properly format the SOAP XML message? I have a working C# application that successfully calls the XmlCommand function. Upon tracing it, I found that the message that was sent in looks like:
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.bio-rad.com/LSG/GXD/CfxComSchema.xsd">
  <RegistrationID />
  <RegisterService />
</Message>**

Comment: The zeep client handles the SOAP envelope for you. I see you have a client instantiated so you should make a call like `client.service.XmlCommand(xml)` but make sure you have some valid values for `RegistrationID` and `RegisterService` and that `xml` is in a proper format expected by the service.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the client is correctly created?

Comment: I would troubleshoot the calls and try to figure out what needs to be part of a correct SOAP request before suspecting that there is something wrong with the zeep client